# Euler's complete works

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

If Euler's works are still being published then what is this?: http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E786.html

Is it only some of his works? I thought "complete works" meant literally all.

Thanks

Comment: The collected works of [Epimenides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimenides_paradox) actually contain a full reproduction of the multi-volume *collected works of Epimenides*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the title ("The Complete Works of L. Euler in French") means that the book contains all works that Euler wrote using the French language. Most of what he published was written in Latin, and maybe some in German, but that is not included here.